# Remove last item from innerText

Tags: javascript, html

I want to remove the last element of innerText, I tried to get the last element by position, but it didn't work.

```
text.innerText[text.innerText.length - 1] = ""
```

Comment: Last element or last character?

Comment: Please add some details. Is it a space character by chance? In that case you can use `trim()`. Also, you have to use `text.innerText = [expression that removes the last item];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use substring or slice like below:

```
var a = text.innerText.substring(0, text.innerText.length - 1);
```

the same way with slice:

```
var a = tex.innerText.slice(0, text.innerText.length - 1);
```

or more simple with slice:

```
var a = tex.innerText.slice(0, -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

In js you can't assign to a "part of the string", like assigning an empty string to the last element in your example.
You should assign your desired value to the innerText of the element.

Something like:

```
text.innerText = text.innerText.substring(0, text.innerText.length - 1)
```

Please read: [innerText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) and [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Comment: Doesn't really work...

Comment: Good point, but the first argument of `substring` is the start index, not the end.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `slice`:

```
text.innerText = text.innerText.slice(0, -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove more than just one character (as per above answers - slice() will do that) - then you could create a function that optionally allows removal of a word or a letter.

You need to get the innerText of the element that you are targeting, split it by character or word, remove the last item, rejoin the characters or words and reset the inneText.

The following allows removing of the last character or word depending on the button clicked

```js
function reduceText(type) {
  const text = document.querySelector('#text');
  let newText;
  type == 'word'
    ? newText = text.innerText.split(' ').slice(0,-1).join(' ')
    : newText = text.innerText.slice(0,-1);
    
  text.innerText = newText
}
```

```html
<p id ="text">There was an old woman who swallowed a fly</p>
<hr/>
<button type="button" onclick="reduceText('letter')">click to remove the last letter</button>
<button type="button" onclick="reduceText('word')">click to remove the last word</button>
```